# Read Geo Coordinates from EXIF data of Photos

Tags: java, android, gps, exif, android-location

I am a .net developer trying to learn Android. I am trying to develop a mobile application using any Android simulator from a Windows desktop.

1. Can you please suggest such an Android simulator for windows 7 desktop?
2. Is it possible to read **EXIF** data from webcam? Or what should be the device used for capturing the coordinates as and when the photo is taken?
3. Can we sent the photo along with the geocordinate to a server application in the same system?
4. What should be the characteristics of the server app? A web service would be a good bet for the server application?
5. Is there a book that demonstrate this kind of an approach in detail?

Note: Please consider this as a programming question since I am trying to do programming with Android for reading EXIF data.

READINGS:

1. [Reading data metadata from JPEG, XMP or EXIF in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280948/reading-data-metadata-from-jpeg-xmp-or-exif-in-c-sharp?rq=1)
2. [How to save GPS coordinates in exif data on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280479/how-to-save-gps-coordinates-in-exif-data-on-android)
3. [How to call built-in camera app from my own application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536802/how-to-call-built-in-camera-app-from-my-own-application-in-android?rq=1)
4. [How to Consume WCF Service with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Android simulator:  http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

You can embed EXIF data / set it when taking the picture before sending it to a remote server for processing.  When posting / sending the data to a remote system, you could send the location data seperate, or leave it as attributes as part of the EXIF data.

[Write/Geotag JPEGs (EXIF data) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531544/write-geotag-jpegs-exif-data-in-android)

From reading the above, my assumption would be that the following would work:

```
 ExifInterface exif;
 exif = new ExifInterface("/sdcard/DCIM/"+filename+".jpeg");
 double exifLatitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
 double exifLongitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
```

More information specific to Android:  [How to save GPS coordinates in exif data on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280479/how-to-save-gps-coordinates-in-exif-data-on-android)

Finally:  [Read EXIF information in a JPEG file, ExifInterface](http://x-tutorials.blogspot.ch/2009/12/read-exif-information-in-jpeg-file.html) which has examples

Comment: probably best to ask another question, more specific to that -- or research on here what other people have done / asked